# Is "Serious Node" correct?

Tags: generic-term

I usually use the sentence *"On a serious node"*. Is it correct?

Comment: It depends on your network, I suppose. But you're probably thinking of the idiom *on a serious **note***.

Comment: It's correct only if you are sick with a code in your node (see earlier question about words for snot).

Answer (score 2):

While this is not grammatically incorrect and I suppose in theory you could parametrize conversation in terms of nodes insofar as nodes are intersection between different strands and conversation are, to extend the metaphor, intersections points between ideas. Under this metaphor, you could transition to a serious node using the phrase, "on a serious node." All that being said, it seems far more likely that you are intending to communicate that you are about to shift the topic of conversation from a less serious note to a more serious note. If this is the case then the conventional phrase is "on a more serious note." You might get weird looks for using "on a serious node."